# how to pass parameters enum in method any?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to parameterize enum? I want to use my enum value in method any? to check true or false for my ActiveRecord

I have method is_any? to check my ActiveRecord

```
  def is_any? status
    album.voice_guides.all_except(params[:ids]).any?(&status?)
  end
```

And call is_any? in this method

```
  def verify_bulk_destroy
    return if album.pending?

    if album.publish?
      raise Api::Error::ControllerRuntimeError, :error unless is_any? 
       (:publish)
    end
  end
```

But it raise error

> ```
>   undefined method `status?' for #<Api::Admin::Albums::PremiumGuidesController:0x0000000000d278>
>    Did you mean?  status
>                   status=
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `is_any?` method to

```
def is_any?(status)
  album.voice_guides.all_except(params[:ids]).any? { |guide| guide.status == status } 
end
```

which will load all records into memory first as your method did before.

Or to this when you want to check the condition in the database without loading the records into memory which might be faster depending on your needs:

```
def is_any?(status)
  album.voice_guides.all_except(params[:ids]).where(status: status).exists?
end
```